# Whats the purpose of the last check in Ember.isEmpty function?

Tags: ember.js

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  return isNone(obj) || (obj.length === 0 && typeof obj !== 'function') || (typeof obj === 'object' && get(obj, 'length') === 0);
}
```

1) For null and undefined, we have isNone() function

2) For [], '', we have the second check.

3) The purpose of third check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is to check for empty objects that have `length` as an Ember computed property. IE8 and below has no support for Javascript computed properties, so you have to use the Ember syntax to compute them.